# How do I fix gaze for zoomed view?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I had created an application for HoloLens and I have deployed the same in my PC. In my application, I have certain buttons. These buttons are supposed to get highlighted when my gaze is on them for the HoloLens and when my mouse is hovering on them for the PC. The HoloLens version works just fine. However, when I am zooming in to get a better view in the PC version, this highlighting feature is not very accurate. Sometimes my mouse is much lower than the button and it's still getting highlighted. I have to zoom in quite close to the sphere in order to highlight the buttons in the first place.

I haven't tried anything to fix this because I am very new to this whole concept of making a HoloLens application work on the PC.

Comment: do never zoom using the mousewheel on the GameView of Unity (changing the `Scale` slider) ... it is shit and basically all it does is scaling up the pixels and thereby (as you noticed) breakes some stuff. Rather move your camera closer etc like you actually would do on the HoloLens (you usually do not zoom on the HoloLens ;) ) If you are using the [MR-Toolkit](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/releases) there should actually be something implemented using the mouse and `W,S,A,D` keys for moving around.

Comment: Oh and also on the PC rather also use the Gaze for interaction. First of all there are sometimes those metnioned conflicts and second it is what you use on the HoloLens so your testing during the development should be as close to the target result as possible

Comment: On scrolling in and out, nothing is breaking in my view. Everything remains intact. It's just that the gaze is causing issues. How do I use Gaze for interaction on the PC?